# How can i change currency format pattern, currency symbol and currency symbol position programmatically in magento 2?

Tags: currency, magento2

I want to change currency format pattern, currency symbol and currency symbol position programmatically. I found some data in folder `vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Locale\Data`. For example:

```
<currencyFormats numberSystem="latn">
    <currencyFormatLength>
        <currencyFormat type="standard">
            <pattern>#,##0.00 ¤</pattern>
        </currencyFormat>
    </currencyFormatLength>
</currencyFormats>
```

And found some class `Magento\Framework\Locale\Currency`, who work with price.
But I don't know how to use it in custom module.